# How to insert column in particular position in sqlite database table

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have created a table and insertion works well and fine.

Now my app needs data to be inserted in specific position in between the table, suppose there are total 10 entries and I want to add a new entry at position 4 and then position of other data gets incremented.

Is there any way I can do it? Any inbuilt method?
Or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: Hi ravalrocks, can you show us some code? You might wanna read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused.  Rows in SQL dbs don't have order.  Unless you put an ORDER BY in your search sql, rows can be returned in any order that's convenient for the db, and there is no promise that the order will be the same if you make the same query twice.  If you wish to order them, you have to do that by placing an order column and maintain it yourself, then adding ORDER BY on that column in all your queries.

Comment: my table has two rows first is id that is auto increment and other have string. now i have to add a column at particular position . the app is music player. and when user clicks on play next then that particular song name should be inserted in next position to the current playing song .

Comment: Autoincrement creates a primary key.  It can be used as an ordering, but is not an ordering.  Its a unique id for a row.  Its impossible to stick something in the middle, because its a unique index.  (you could to a limited degree on some more complex dbs by making the autoincrement count by more than 1, but I don't think sqlite can do that.  And even then it isn't reliable if you're frequently using the hack).  I really suggest you study some relational theory so you understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: yeh i got it i need to update my table with new entries thanks man

Answer (score -1):

The statement to insert a new record is:

`INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME [(column1,column2, column3,...columnN)] VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...valueN);`

So what you have to do is select the colums that you want to insert and fill the values, if the columns you **don't** select don't have a default value you have to set one value for them.

And required columns is a must have a value